# Wordpress 301 redirect, after permalink change from %day% to %id%

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

On a Wordpress blog, with *posts* permalink setup like this: `/%year%/%month%/%day%/%post_name%/`

How to massively change the permalinks to this: `/%post_name%-%post_id%/`.
I have about 10,000 articles.

1. Change the permalink from wordpress settings - done.
2. Create a redirection for all link `/1970/01/01/this_is_a_post/`

How to do the step 2?

People will arrive on `/1970/01/01/this_is_a_post` but they will find a 404 as the post is now under `/this_is_a_post-00022`.

Comment: I fixed the issue by exporting / filtering / Importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

1. Download the WordPress Simple 301 Redirect plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/
2. Create a redirect and enter the following in the request field: `/%year%/%month%/%day%/%post_name%/` and the following in the destination field: `/%post_name%-%post_id%/`
3. Voila! You're all done.

Comment: indeed i tested this method, when you look at the source code of the plugin, it's comparing strict string to the url. %year% != 2006. 
I think i have to code a plugin, but even with that. From a post-name, I'll have to find the post, so i need to make one SQL request. That's the only solution that i see.